# Update the name of Excel Worksheet dynamically- VBA excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a macro where i can equate the name of a worksheet to a cell value.
So far i have only been able to extract name of the worksheet and put it to a cell value.

Is there a way i can achieve the above?

Thanks

Comment: `Sheet1.Name = "Did you even try anything"`

Comment: If you show the VBA code you used to set a cell value to the worksheet name, we can show you how to switch the left-hand side with the right-hand side so that it does what you want.

Comment: Function TabName3(cell As Range)
    TabName3 = cell.Worksheet.Name
End Function

Comment: Add that information to the question itself.  There is an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47408286/edit) link just below the question that you can use.

Comment: You might like to also show how you are invoking that function.  It looks like you are using it as a UDF with a dummy argument.  If you are using a UDF, you need to be aware that a UDF can only officially return a value to the cell which contains the UDF, i.e. you can't write one that will modify the state of Excel (such as changing sheet names).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is already a solution to this,
Follow this [link](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2762-excel-dynamic-name-sheets-from-cell-values.html)

Credit to folks at Extendoffice.com

Pasting code here for reference, just follow the link you'll find details

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Set Target = Range("A1")
If Target = "" Then Exit Sub
Application.ActiveSheet.Name = VBA.Left(Target, 31)
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: If I'm not totally blind then this is run **every time the selection of a sheet changes**. That means **every time** you click a cell the active sheet gets renamed to the value in A1. How wasteful is this? Also the `Exit Sub` right before `End Sub` is a totally waste. See my solution for a slim solution that runs only when the specific cell changed!

Comment: made the edit for `exit sub`, thanks for pointing out, please note that the code is not mine, I just pasted it here, however, your first concern's validity will differ from user to user. He may or may not want to do it every time there's a cell change.

Comment: Obviously you may want to change the sheet name whenever it **needs** to be changed which is whenever the cell content changes? Your approach runs when you click a cell, this way it is a randomly called event which doesn't make much sens in my eyes.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve this with the `Worksheet_Change` event of the worksheet.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'note that A1 here is the cell that contains the sheet name. Adjust it to your needs.
    If Target.Address(False, False) = "A1" Then
        Target.Parent.Name = Target.Text
    End If
End Sub
```

Every time the value of A1 changes, the worksheet name changes accordingly.

*Note this procedure has to be  in a worksheet scope not within a module.*

---

It can be useful to implement an error handling for not allowed or empty sheet names.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'note that A1 here is the cell that contains the sheet name. Adjust it to your needs.
    If Target.Address(False, False) = "A1" And Target.Text <> vbNullString Then
        On Error GoTo ERR_NO_RENAME
        Target.Parent.Name = Target.Text
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If

    Exit Sub
ERR_NO_RENAME:
    If Err Then MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, Err.Number, Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
End Sub
```